# How to force a Website in Heroku to always reload cache upon visiting the page?

Tags: php, html, css, heroku

I'm very new to cloud hosting... (Only learned basic git a few days ago)

I'm working on a Website and I generally have to make very small changes at a time, (something like changing someone's name or a typo) and that causes the website to not change for people who have the website cached before I made the small change.

I was wondering if there is anything I could do to make the website always reload the cache whenever someone access it. So I know for sure they will always have the latest version without having to delete their cache.

Comment: What code stack are you using on the site?